# Will Grub Booter Break my main OS

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, grub, kali-linux

I am using a virtual machine. When I install Kali Linux to the virtual machine, it asks me if I want to install the GRUB boot loader.

If I do this, will it break my main computer‘s operating system?

Comment: As long as you're installing in a VM, your host machine isn't affected. It's probably not necessary to install though, Kali is designed to boot from live media.

Comment: Use the full Kali package. Get the ISO file and install that. I am working in Kali 2020.3 now and it is a VM within VMware Workstation. No impact at all on the host machine.

Comment: i have 2020.3 64bit  using Debian 64 on the vm when i made it and when i didn't install it just was a black screen terminal when i tried to start it after the installation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are referring to the following question near the end of the Kali Linux installation process:

> Install the GRUB boot loader to the master boot record?

Given that you are installing Kali in a virtual machine, you can safely answer "Yes" to this question. It will proceed to install GRUB to the master boot record of the *virtual* hard drive of the virtual machine.

Your host machine will not be affected at all.

Comment: thank you, i am accepting this as the answer